# Grails UrlMappings for Rest and other actions

Tags: grails

I have a controller which is primarily used for REST communication using the `show`, `update`, `save` and `delete` actions. This is mapped accordingly in the `UrlMappings.groovy` file and works just fine.

I then have a need for calling the `getAccountTypesByEnv` action in the same controller, but I have had some trouble to set up a syntax which actually works.

The below definition works, but I was wondering whether there is an easier and more correct way of doing it.

```
"/ext/accounttype/$id?"(controller: "accountType") {
    action = [GET: 'show', PUT: 'update', POST: 'save', DELETE: 'delete']
    "/ext/accounttype/getAccountTypesByEnv"(controller: "accountType", action: "getAccountTypesByEnv")
}
```

**Update**

I ended up dividing this into 2 separate generic mappings as displayed below:

```
"/ext/$controller/$id?" {
     action = [GET: 'show', PUT: 'update', POST: 'save', DELETE: 'delete']
}

"/ext/$controller/action/$customAction?" {
     action = { return params.customAction }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define in your `UrlMappings.groovy` like:

```
 "/ext/$controller/$resourceId?/$customAction?" {
    action = {
        Map actionMethodMap = [GET: params.resourceId ? "show" : "index", POST: "save", PUT: "update", DELETE: "delete"]

        return params.customAction ?: actionMethodMap[request.method.toUpperCase()]
    }
    id = {
        if (params.resourceId == "action") {
            return params.id
        }
        return params.resourceId
    }
}
```

This is the most generic `UrlMapping` I think for now which you can use here in the following way:

```
GET     "/ext/accounttype" will call **index** action of AccounttypeController
POST    "/ext/accounttype" will call save action of AccounttypeController
PUT     "/ext/accounttype/14" will call update action of AccounttypeController with id 14
DELETE  "/ext/accounttype/14" will call update action of AccounttypeController with id 14
GET     "/ext/accounttype/14" will call show action of AccounttypeController with id 14
GET     "/ext/accounttype/action/getAccountTypesByEnv" will call getAccountTypesByEnv action of AccounttypeController with null id
GET     "/ext/accounttype/action/getAccountTypesByEnv?id=143" will call getAccountTypesByEnv action of AccounttypeController with id 143
```

Comment: Very nice. I will test that monday. What about the controller case issue? Doesn't your suggestion imply that $controller is 'accountType' and not 'accounttype' ?

Comment: Sure. Yes the controller name in the example can be `accountType`

Comment: I had some problems getting this to work, but your solution inspired me to use a generic solution where I just use 2 separate mappings.